# How to serialize request.POST data?

Tags: python, django, serialization, encryption

My story: Getting bank details from users (i want safe here )

1. getting the information from form
2. serialize it ( don't know how to do this )
3. encrypt
4. save encrypted value into table field.

The second point bit confused me. How to serialize it .? ( ? through django.core.serializers or pickle )

I tried without serialize like save `request.POST['value']` into `var` `{}` then convert `var` into `encrypt` and save to db.

But when i decrypt this value from db i am getting `"{'bank_details': u'email@gmail.com'}"` I know i can't use this unless i remove the `""`.

Tell me How to serialize request.POST data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `json` module.
Here is link for it. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
....
# you can save your data into json format
data = json.dumps(request.POST['value'])
# then you can do some encrypted work and save it to db
data=encrypted(data)
db_connect.save(data)
# now you can get data from db which is still in the form "{1:22}"
# with json.loads you will never see "" again
new_data = db_connect.get(data)
new_data = json.loads(new_data)
print new_data
....
```

Comment: @rajasimon What's the format of your original data? Try with "{'paypalEmail':'getnew@gmail.com'}".

Comment: @rajasimon It seems {'paypalEmail': '"getnew@gmail.com"'} is different from what you described in the question. Never mind. 'Expecting property name' error raises when you try to parse something not json with json. Can you turn the data format to "{'paypalEmail':'getnew@gmail.com'}" when you construct the dictionary?